# How to demonstrate the correctness of a program with a while cycle using Hoare's logic?

Tags: logic, proof, computation-theory, proof-of-correctness, hoare-logic

How can I demonstrate through Hoare logic the correctness of a program that has a while cycle. It would be fascinating that some one develop it with any example, due to as my problem to solve is:

> Precondition={n>0}

```
cont := n;
sum := 0;
while cont <> 0 do:
    sum := sum + cont;
    cont := cont-1;
endwhile
```

> Postcondition={sum=1+2+...+n}

It is not necessary to develop this example. I just need to understand the procedure because I don't have a practical example. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hoare logic's ["while" rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoare_logic#While_rule) must be applied here:

> If a command `S` satisfies a Hoare triple of the form `{P ∧ B} S {P}`, then the command `while B do S` satisfies `{P} while B do S {P ∧ ¬B}`.

This is the only technique for proving the postcondition of a `while` loop in Hoare logic, so you must apply it. The condition `B` and the loop body `S` are given in the code, but `P` can be any condition you choose so long as `{P ∧ B} S {P}` holds.

This Hoare triple asserts that if `P` is true before an iteration of the loop then it will still be true afterwards, so such a condition `P` is known as a [loop invariant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_invariant). To prove the postcondition of the loop you need to establish (1) that `P` is true before the first iteration of the loop, and (2) that `P` is preserved by the loop body.

The necessary invariant for the loop in your example is `sum = n + (n-1) + ... + (cont+1)`, i.e. the sum of the numbers from `cont+1` to `n`. In general, there is no systematic way to find the right loop invariant to use; you have to use your understanding of the algorithm, and your intuition/experience to come up with one yourself.

---

This is sufficient to show that *if* the loop terminates then its postcondition will be satisfied; you also need to establish that the loop *does* terminate. The technique you should apply here is to find a [loop variant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_variant); this is usually some integer quantity which (1) decreases on each iteration of the loop, and (2) causes the loop to terminate when the quantity reaches zero.

In your example, `cont` is a loop variant, because the loop decrements `cont := cont-1`, and the loop condition terminates the loop when `cont` reaches zero. In general, like finding a useful invariant, there is no systematic procedure which finds a variant in all cases, but you can start by looking at the loop condition to see which variable(s) determine when the loop terminates.